# How is this was derived? DTFT for symmetric pulse

Tags: math, dtft

do not understand how the middle expression was derived from above expression, 
[image]

after all summation\multiplication i get:

$$\frac{e^{-jwN} + e^{jwN} - e^{-jw(N+1)} + e^{jw(N+1)}}{2 - e^{-jw} - e^{jw}}$$

Comment: what was the original question? what's the range of pulse in $n$ ?

Comment: @Fat32 from -N to N inclusive. But I don't think it really matters, I think it's just a matter of arithmetic manipulation only.

Comment: it does not matter for the DTFT magnitude but it matters for the phase of the filter which is dependent on the summing range. So you have this summation: $$ X(e^{j \omega}) = \sum_{n=-N}^{N} e^{-j \omega n} $$ ?

Comment: @Fat32 yes, I add the whole derivation) I just didn't get how they transform this to Euler function for sinusoid. So I want to know the trick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the following trick will be useful: 
$$ e^{j a} - e^{j b} =  e^{j \frac{a+b}{2}} \left( e^{j \frac{a-b}{2}} - e^{j \frac{b-a}{2}} \right) $$

Then simply expand the sum as:
$$ X(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{n=-N}^{N}e^{-j\omega n} = \frac{ e^{-j\omega (-N)} - e^{-j\omega (N+1)} }{1 - e^{-j\omega}} = \frac{ e^{j\omega N} - e^{-j\omega (N+1)} }{1 - e^{-j\omega}} $$

Apply the trick to the numerator and denominator by recognising $a$ and $b$ carrefully: for the numerator $a=\omega N$ and $b=-\omega (N+1)$ whereas for the denominator $a=0$ and $b=-\omega$ which yields:

$$ X(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{ e^{j\omega N} - e^{-j\omega (N+1)} }{1 - e^{-j\omega}} = \frac{ e^{j \frac{\omega N -\omega (N+1) }{2}} \left( e^{j\frac{\omega N +\omega (N+1) }{2}} - e^{-j\frac{\omega N +\omega (N+1) }{2}} \right) }{ e^{-j\omega/2} \left( e^{j\omega/2}  - e^{-j\omega/2} \right) }$$

which simplifies to:
$$ X(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{ e^{-j\omega/2}  \left( e^{j\frac{\omega N +\omega (N+1) }{2}} - e^{-j\frac{\omega N +\omega (N+1) }{2}} \right) }{ e^{-j\omega/2} \left( e^{j\omega/2}  - e^{-j\omega/2} \right) } = \frac{  e^{j \omega \frac{2N+1 }{2}} - e^{-j \omega \frac{2N+1}{2}} }{   e^{j\omega/2}  - e^{-j\omega/2}  }  $$

which is:
$$ X(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{  \sin( \omega (N+\frac{1}{2}) )}{   \sin( \omega \frac{1}{2}) }  $$